# Symfony2 application admin and user area

Tags: php, symfony

I am starting a project with symfony2 framework and i need to have 2 type of users, admin and simple user. It is correct to create 2 bundles, one for each type of user like areas in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have like a admin area that is complete different from your user area, then I would say create a BUndle for each. If for example the adminarea just got some additional functionality, then keep it in one Bundle. 
I'm not sure about ASP.NET but in Symfony a Bundle is a complete application closed in itself. For example a Blog or a Forum is a Bundle. Or something simple like a Pagination can also be a Bundle.

Comment: It is good idea to have 1 bundle for large application or its is code smell?

Comment: This is up to you. You can smash everything is just one Bundle and that is totally fine. I just like to put stuff that seems to me like a unit or something that could be reusable in other projects in a bundles. Have a look at this one http://knpbundles.com/ to get a better feeling of a bundle